# How to properly refer to attribute generated with data method in vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I have an application which contains a section with a list of users with a searchbox to search names, the information comes from a database & i store this values in app.users.
I created a component called ‘user’ which is used to display the information of that specific user, this
component contains a ‘show’ attribute, which i use in order to hide the user name from a list when the user name does not match with the input field.

```
watch : {
input_field(){

this.users.forEach(element => {
    if(element.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.input_field.toLowerCase()) == -1 ){
        element.show = false
    }else{
        console.log('Show ' + element.name)
        element.show = true
    }
});
}
}
```

This is not working, the reason is because i am refering to an array insted of vue components, and when i change the ‘show’ attribute it seems like that doesn’t even exist. I fixed this by generating an array of all of the vue components which name is ‘user’ and changing the ‘show’ attribute from there.
This works but i don’t think this is the correct approach. Can someone help me on how to change the
‘show’ attribute from the original array without searching for the components instance?

I will leave a link to jsfiddle with my current code

https://jsfiddle.net/jbnko9L3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you want to filter the users array based on the input field value
You can simply achieve this by using `computed` properties in vue.

I have updated the fiddle code here,
https://jsfiddle.net/nsv7z8ty/2/